# How do i solve this "chicken vs egg" declaration issue?

Tags: c++, arduino, raspberry-pi-pico

New with C++ but been coding a lot of ObjC back in the day. So i thought i was smart trying to solve a cross reference issue with the old delegate pattern used widely in ObjC but only managed to move the issue it to another file .

Im trying to reach the invoker of the file by passing it as a reference, conforming to a "interface".

```
#pragma once

#include <libUI.h>
#include <Arduino.h>

class PeripheralDelegate {
public:
    virtual void pushViewController(PeripheralViewController* vc) = 0;
    virtual void popLastViewController() = 0;
};

class PeripheralViewController: public ViewController {
private:
    PeripheralDelegate* mDelegate;
public:
    PeripheralViewController(): ViewController(), mDelegate() {}
    PeripheralViewController(String id, Rect frame, PeripheralDelegate* delegate): ViewController(id, frame), mDelegate(delegate) {}
    virtual ~PeripheralViewController() {}
    virtual void encoderValueChanged(int newVal, int oldVal) = 0;
    virtual void encoderSwitchPressed() = 0;
    virtual void backButtonPressed() = 0;
    virtual void firstButtonPressed() = 0;
    virtual void secondButtonPressed() = 0;
};
```

Also, all kind of feedback on the code is much appriciated!

Comment: [What are forward declarations and their uses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757565/what-are-forward-declarations-in-c).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can predeclare `PeripheralViewController` and then you can use a pointer to it:

```
class PeripheralViewController;
```

Comment: IOW: put `class PeripheralViewController;` right before `class PeripheralDelegate {....`.

Answer (score 2):

I often use interfaces to break dependencies (on implementation).
And that would work here too. Using interfaces helps writing unit tests too.

```
#pragma once

#include <libUI.h>
#include <Arduino.h>

class ViewController
{
};

class PeripheralViewControllerItf
{
    // abstract methods here (the ones that PeripheralDelegate needs)
};

class PeripheralDelegate 
{
public:
    virtual void pushViewController(PeripheralViewControllerItf& vc) = 0; // I prefer reference since it shouldn't accept nullptr's 
    virtual void popLastViewController() = 0;
};

class PeripheralViewController : 
    public PeripheralViewControllerItf,
    public ViewController 
{
private:
    PeripheralDelegate* mDelegate;
public:
    PeripheralViewController() : ViewController(), mDelegate() {}
    PeripheralViewController(String id, Rect frame, PeripheralDelegate* delegate) : ViewController(id, frame), mDelegate(delegate) {}
    virtual ~PeripheralViewController() {}
    virtual void encoderValueChanged(int newVal, int oldVal) = 0;
    virtual void encoderSwitchPressed() = 0;
    virtual void backButtonPressed() = 0;
    virtual void firstButtonPressed() = 0;
    virtual void secondButtonPressed() = 0;
};
```